# markdown doesn't work in R

Tags: r, markdown

I would like to make a markdown wih a r code, but it says without code each time, so in the markdown file, there is just my code and text. Furthermore the code structure is not respected. Do you know why it doesn't work ? i didn't find some answer...

````
> ```{r setup, include=FALSE} knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE) ```
> 
> # Assignment
> 
> ## First question
> 
> We read the dataset in "data" and we make the column "date" as date
> format
> 
> '''{r} data<-read.csv(file="activity.csv",header=TRUE)
> data$date<-as.Date(as.character(data$date),"%Y-%m-%d") '''
> 
> ## Second question
> 
> Histogram of the total number of steps taken each day
> 
> '''{r} library("ggplot2")
> perday<-aggregate(data$steps,list(Date=data$date),sum)
> qplot(perday$x,main="Histogram of the total number of steps taken each
> day",xlab="Number of steps") '''
````

It did the same output that above.

I don't understand why...

Comment: When embedding code, make sure you're using the back quote (`) instead of single quote ('). See section 5 in the following: https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/rmarkdown-cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: thank you for the document, it will be useful

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is when creating the code chunk. it should be like this:

````
```{r}
# your code here
```
````

with backquote ` (Ctrl + Alt + 7 ou AltGr + 7 on windows) and not simple quote '

The easiest way to create Rmarkdown is to use RStudio and use the button or keyboard shortcut to insert a chunk. it is Ctrl + Alt + i on windows.

Your correct code should be

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
 knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# Assignment

## First question

We read the dataset in "data" and we make the column "date" as date format

```{r} 
data<-read.csv(file="activity.csv",header=TRUE)
data$date<-as.Date(as.character(data$date),"%Y-%m-%d"
```

## Second question

Histogram of the total number of steps taken each day

```{r} 
library("ggplot2")
perday<-aggregate(data$steps,list(Date=data$date),sum)
qplot(perday$x,main="Histogram of the total number of steps taken each
 day",xlab="Number of steps")
```
````